# Realm primary key migration - objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, core-data-migration, realm-migration

Old RLMObject is there below and primaryKey is AttributeId. I want to change this key to @"Id" next build.

UserItemObject.m

```
@implementation UserItemObject {

}

+ ( NSString * )primaryKey; {
    return @"AttributeId";
}

@end
```

UserItemObject.h

```
@interface UserItemObject : RLMObject
   @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *Id;
   @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *AttributeId;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(UserItemObject)
```

And then I wrote some code to AppDelegate;

```
  [RLMRealm setSchemaVersion:1 forRealmAtPath:[RLMRealm defaultRealmPath] withMigrationBlock:^(RLMMigration *migration, NSUInteger oldSchemaVersion) {
      if ( oldSchemaVersion < 1 ) {
          [migration enumerateObjects: UserItemObject.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
                newObject[ @"primaryKeyProperty" ] = @"Id";
          }];
      }
  }];
```

This code give me an error ;

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid property name'
```

How can I solve this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried giving it a different name other than `Id`? Just for the sake of trial - `userID` for example. Maybe there is some internal problem with the name `Id`...

Comment: I tried before but can not solved :/

Answer (score 1):

To change the primary key property, you'll need to change the return value of `+[UserItemObject primaryKey]`.

Then, to actually do the migration, you'll do:

```
[RLMRealm setSchemaVersion:1 forRealmAtPath:[RLMRealm defaultRealmPath] withMigrationBlock:^(RLMMigration *migration, NSUInteger oldSchemaVersion) {
      if ( oldSchemaVersion < 1 ) {
          [migration enumerateObjects: UserItemObject.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
                newObject[ @"Id" ] = oldObject[@"AttributeId"];
          }];
      }
  }];
```